# strtotime conversion: only date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, iso8601

So I'm trying to take a date I have stored in a string, and increment it by one week 9 times. (I want 10 dates total).

The value of `$start_date` is initially: `2013-12-04 12:00`, but when I increment it it becomes:

```
606813 
then: 
1211613
1816413 and so on.
```

I understand that the formatting will change, but I don't understand why I am getting the results that I do. The second returned number seems to imply:

12(month)11(day)6(some unkown thing)13(year)

which would be a week, but the first and third returned numbers doesn't make sense at all unless there is a 60th and 18th month of the year I'm not aware of, and they're all missing a time to go along with the date.

This is my first attempt to use `strtotime()` so I'm not sure what I'm doing, but I have tried to work through this and I could use any help you can offer.

```
$start_date = $row["start_time"];

for ( $i = 1; $i<9; $i++) {
    $start_date= strtotime('+1 week', $start_date);
    $arr = array('id' => $row["course_id"],
        'title' => $row["course_name"],
        'start' => $start_date,
        'allDay' => false
    );
    array_push($result, $arr);
}
```

Comment: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns `int` timestamp not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns int and the second parameter (if used) should be a valid timestamp. Also if you want to get the date string you can use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$start_date = strtotime('2013-12-04 12:00');

for ( $i = 1; $i<9; $i++){
    $start_date= strtotime('+1 week', $start_date);
    $arr = array('id' => $row["course_id"],
             'title' => $row["course_name"],
             'start' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$start_date),
             'allDay' => false
             );
        array_push($result, $arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To increment time with strtotime I had to first convert the start date before any increments are done, otherwise it considers $startdate to be the "epoch" and creates dates in the 70s.

```
              //changed here
$start_date = strtotime($row["start_time"]);

for ( $i = 1; $i<9; $i++){
    $start_date= strtotime('+1 week', $start_date);
    $arr = array('id' => $row["course_id"],
                 'title' => $row["course_name"],
                 'start' => $start_date,
                 'allDay' => false
                 );
            array_push($result, $arr);
        }
```